# recover grails url mappings

Tags: grails, h2

I have been handed a deployed grails app as a .war, after installing it, I later unpacked it to view sources and configs.

Is there anyway to find out the UrlMappings that were originally in the source?  They don't seem to be anywhere in the war.

I have no access to the source, or app authors, and the app's load page is a login page.  There's an h2 database, which I explored but found that it has no tables in the public schema.

Then I also found some views in ./WEB-INF/grails-app/views/connection, such as create.gsp and editConnection.gsp and also a JDBDriver folder with create.gsp.

My thinking is that there's a url to setup this app, but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Grails url mappings are declared in a file called `UrlMappings.groovy` so you might try decompiling this class. UrlMappings typically make heavy use of Closures so you will likely have a bunch of related classes to decompile as well.